# PHP MYSQL : how to keep the variable alive till connection ends

Tags: php, mysql

i want to keep some variable alive so that it is available to all the pages of the site ;
i tried global but that don't work with these kind of problem ;
i use the following code :

```
 while($result1 = mysql_fetch_array( $result)) 
  {   
  $adm_no = $result1['adm_no']; 
  $adm_dt = $result1['adm_dt']; 
  $name = $result1['name']; 
  $dob = $result1['dob']; 
  $f_name = $result1['f_name']; 
  $f_office = $result1['f_office']; 
  $f_o_no = $result1['f_o_no']; 
  $m_name = $result1['m_name']; 
  $m_office = $result1['m_office']; 
  $addr = $result1['addr']; 
  $pho_no = $result['pho_no'];
```

these same variable in another page called tc.php . how can i do that ????

Comment: hmmm Try Read Something before asking. Session Would help you

Comment: Use session as others are saying.. plus notice the last line `$pho_no = $result['pho_no'];` , It should be `$pho_no = $result1['pho_no'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access all that data again in another page I would recommend storing the information needed to retrieve data from your mysql table in a session rather than the result of the query. This means you don't have a load of trivial data in your session space. For example.

Imagine I have a person table and want to get bits of information for that person on different pages I just store the person_id in a session like so:

```
//home.php
$_SESSION['personID'] = $personID;
```

Then on any page I want to retrieve person information on I just get the person id from the session and run the query to get the specific information I need.

```
//profile.php
$personID = $_SESSION['personID'];

//Get specific information here
```

If you really cant change the way that you are doing this which I really hope you can as it'll make your life a hell of a lot easier then just changing your code to this:

```
//make sure that you have started a session at the top of your page before you do anything else
session_start();

while($result1 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {   
    $_SESSION['adm_no'] = $result1['adm_no']; 
    $_SESSION['adm_dt'] = $result1['adm_dt']; 
    $_SESSION['name'] = $result1['name']; 
    $_SESSION['dob'] = $result1['dob']; 
    //etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$_SESSION['myvar']= "your value";

echo $_SESSION['myvar'];
```

will can access any page

Answer (score 0):

Fetch data again in `tc.php` - it is the best way in this case I think.

You can also set that data to the session, and in `tc.php` get it from there.

Comment: i cant fetch it again ..i cant have variable to fetch data ,i made it like that